# How to initiate a function when $ajax() is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery that is.

I would like something that works as the success-pararameter, but that is run when the function is called, rather than once I get the response.

sample (oajax is an extension of ajax for open auth)

```
$.oajax({
            url: url,
            jso_provider: "facebook", // Will match the config identifier
            jso_scopes: false, // List of scopes (OPTIONAL)
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                fbposts=data.data

                //a bunch of code irellevant for the question

            },//success done
            error: function() {
                console.log("ERROR Custom callback()");
            }
        })
};
```

Comment: How can it be a "success" function if you haven't received a response yet? You have no idea whether it was successful.

Comment: I want code that runs before I know if it's success...

Comment: In that case you can simply put it right after the line that calls the ajax, or use one of the [Global Ajax Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for [`.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) ?

> Attach a function to be executed before an Ajax request is sent.

This function (and `.ajaxComplete` et al) allow you to register callback functions that are called for the different phases of *every* AJAX request.

Comment: I looked at that, but as far as I understood, you had to add that to the DOM?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren you have to attach it to any element (`document.body` would do)

Answer (score 0):

In a normal ajax function, you pass it as [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR, status){
                // CODE HERE
            },
            success: function(data) {
                fbposts=data.data
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("ERROR Custom callback()");
            }
        })
};
```

You'll have to check if oajax have this event too, but it probably do